# Copy down Formula in Google Sheets when cell is edited with any number or text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I have been working on a script to copy a formula down when a cell is edited to Yes in the column next to. This is working.
My question is I'd like to copy down the formula if there's a text or number in that a cell. 
How can I add this my script.

I am fairly knew to this so any advice or documentation would be appreciated.

```
function onEdit(){
  var sheetNameToWatch = "Request for Purchases";
  var columnNumberToWatch = 10; 
  var valueToWatch="Yes";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.getRange("K2").setFormula("=(c2*d2)");

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var val = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue();

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && val==valueToWatch  ) {
    var targetCell = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), range.getColumn()+1);
    var d = ss.getRange("K2").copyTo(targetCell);


  }
}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to set the formula in K2 only if there is a text or a number in K2? Your problem is that you don't know how to set that condition? Also, you want this only for row 2 or for all rows with data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what your trying to do?

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='Request for Purchases') return;
  if(e.range.columnStart==10 && e.value="Yes" ) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setFormula("=(C2*D2)");
  }
}
```